# Имена файла для скачивания в .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Допустим, лежит у меня в папке фаил  111.rar. Можно ли отдавать его под разными именами?Например, задать правило, если запрашиваем любой файл, то отдавать его. Например:  `http://site.ru/uploads/first.rar`, на самом деле отдадим ему `111.rar`, но под названием `first.rar`.

Помню давно делал нечто подобное при переименовывании мр3 файлов.

П.с имена заранее неизвестны. их миллионы, поэтому прописывать все глупо.

Answer (score 2):

Ну если файлов миллионы, то не лучше ли перенаправлять все запросы в папке uploads на какой-нибудь php-скрипт примерно таким образом:

```
RewriteEngine on 
#htaccess лежит в папке /uploads
RewriteBase /uploads/
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_MYFLAG} ^$
#index.php тоже лежит в папке /uploads
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ index.php?file=$1 [L,E=MYFLAG:1]
```

Пусть скрипт сделает все что вам надо, под каким надо именем файл отдаст и все дела.

**UPD.**

Например можно использовать такую пхп-функцию (ей хоть размер файла ставьте 1 байт):

```
function file_download($filename, $mimetype='application/octet-stream') {
   if (file_exists($filename)) {
     header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . ' 200 OK');
     header('Content-Type: ' . $mimetype);
     header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('r', filemtime($filename)));
     header('ETag: ' . sprintf('%x-%x-%x', fileinode($filename), filesize($filename), filemtime($filename)));
     header('Content-Length: ' . (filesize($filename)));
     header('Connection: close');
     header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($filename) .'";');
     $f=fopen($filename, 'r');
     while(!feof($f)) {
       echo fread($f, 1024);
       flush();
     }
     fclose($f);
     exit;
   } else {
     echo "Нет такого файла";
   }

}
```

Comment: Немного не так выразился. Не файлов миллионы, а вариантов имен. а отдаваться будет всегда 1 фаил.
Не хотелось через скрипт т.к думаю апач справится с этим с меньшей нагрузкой

Comment: Смотрите Header set в mod_headers.
Должно быть что-то вроде:

    <Files *.*> 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L,E=FILENAME:$1]
    ForceType application/octet-stream
    Header set Content-Disposition "attachment; filename=e.rar"
    </Files> 

Только имя файла e.rar надо как-то динамически менять. Как - не знаю. mod_headers.so не забудьте в apache включить.